# vb.net + mysql - Search table for top 5 rows that are the most similar to input values

Tags: mysql, vb.net, match

I have a Database with many columns, one of them containing Names.

My vb.net software acts as telegram server and waits for the user to send its full name.

The database could have its name spelled differently, for example "Marco Dell'Orso" could be spelled "Marco Dellorso" or "Marco Dell Orso" od "Dell Orso Marco" or whatever. The user could also misspell his name and invert two letters.. for esample "MaCRo Dell'Orso"

I would need a way to return the 5 rows that are the most similar to the words used in the query. What would be the best way? I was thinking of splitting the name on whitechars and then use LIKE in the query with the single words, but that does not work with mistyped words.

EDIT:

My current plan is to that if the database contains more than one or less then one rows with the exact name, then split the input into the single words and return all strings that contain ANY of the input words. this should reduce the rows to analyze from 42000 to a few hundred. Once I have these few hundred lines, i could run a Levenshtein function on the rows and return the 5  most matching..

Is this a good idea?

Comment: There is the SOUNDEX http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995150/how-to-search-for-soundex-substrings-in-mysql function but in my experience it has some problem with non-english words and you are talking about italian firstnames and lastnames

Comment: as far as I understand soundex won't work if for example the name is inverted.. (Marco dell orso -> Dell orso marco)

Comment: Levenshtein is not the best choice in this case. You should use a function, that will give you a similarity in percent. This is much more easy than a distance function in your case. Edit: found a really great answer at SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315231/how-to-compare-strings-for-percentage-match-using-vb-net

Comment: this wont work if words are inverted... it would give a high percentage of mismatch.

Comment: It was only an example for such a function There are lots in the WWW of these. Maybe, to catch your problem with inverted words, you could split your string and compare pairwise. It took me a few years to learn what the best way for me is ;-)

Comment: found a working solution! posting the answer

Answer (score 1):

Solved it this way by combining my custom function with a premade Levenshtein function from this link: [How to calculate distance similarity measure of given 2 strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453731/how-to-calculate-distance-similarity-measure-of-given-2-strings) . I assign a score for each single word that appears in the other wordcomplex. then I add a score based on the Levenshtein comparison of each word to another. works great:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    calc()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyUp
    calc()
End Sub


Sub calc()
    Label1.Text = compare(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
End Sub

Public Function compare(source As String, target As String) As Integer
    Dim score As Double

    Dim sourcewords As String() = source.Split(New Char() {" "c, "'"c, "`"c, "´"c})
    Dim targetwords As String() = target.Split(New Char() {" "c, "'"c, "`"c, "´"c})

    For Each s In sourcewords
        If target.Contains(s) Then score = score + 1
        For Each t In targetwords
            score = score + 1 / (DamerauLevenshteinDistance(s, t, 100) + 1)
        Next
    Next

    For Each s In targetwords
        If source.Contains(s) Then score = score + 1
        For Each t In sourcewords
            score = score + 1 / (DamerauLevenshteinDistance(s, t, 100) + 1)
        Next
    Next



    Return score
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Computes the Damerau-Levenshtein Distance between two strings, represented as arrays of
''' integers, where each integer represents the code point of a character in the source string.
''' Includes an optional threshhold which can be used to indicate the maximum allowable distance.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="source">An array of the code points of the first string</param>
''' <param name="target">An array of the code points of the second string</param>
''' <param name="threshold">Maximum allowable distance</param>
''' <returns>Int.MaxValue if threshhold exceeded; otherwise the Damerau-Leveshteim distance between the strings</returns>
Public Shared Function DamerauLevenshteinDistance(source As String, target As String, threshold As Integer) As Integer

    Dim length1 As Integer = source.Length
    Dim length2 As Integer = target.Length

    ' Return trivial case - difference in string lengths exceeds threshhold
    If Math.Abs(length1 - length2) > threshold Then
        Return Integer.MaxValue
    End If

    ' Ensure arrays [i] / length1 use shorter length 
    If length1 > length2 Then
        Swap(target, source)
        Swap(length1, length2)
    End If

    Dim maxi As Integer = length1
    Dim maxj As Integer = length2

    Dim dCurrent As Integer() = New Integer(maxi) {}
    Dim dMinus1 As Integer() = New Integer(maxi) {}
    Dim dMinus2 As Integer() = New Integer(maxi) {}
    Dim dSwap As Integer()

    For i As Integer = 0 To maxi
        dCurrent(i) = i
    Next

    Dim jm1 As Integer = 0, im1 As Integer = 0, im2 As Integer = -1

    For j As Integer = 1 To maxj

        ' Rotate
        dSwap = dMinus2
        dMinus2 = dMinus1
        dMinus1 = dCurrent
        dCurrent = dSwap

        ' Initialize
        Dim minDistance As Integer = Integer.MaxValue
        dCurrent(0) = j
        im1 = 0
        im2 = -1

        For i As Integer = 1 To maxi

            Dim cost As Integer = If(source(im1) = target(jm1), 0, 1)

            Dim del As Integer = dCurrent(im1) + 1
            Dim ins As Integer = dMinus1(i) + 1
            Dim [sub] As Integer = dMinus1(im1) + cost

            'Fastest execution for min value of 3 integers
            Dim min As Integer = If((del > ins), (If(ins > [sub], [sub], ins)), (If(del > [sub], [sub], del)))

            If i > 1 AndAlso j > 1 AndAlso source(im2) = target(jm1) AndAlso source(im1) = target(j - 2) Then
                min = Math.Min(min, dMinus2(im2) + cost)
            End If

            dCurrent(i) = min
            If min < minDistance Then
                minDistance = min
            End If
            im1 += 1
            im2 += 1
        Next
        jm1 += 1
        If minDistance > threshold Then
            Return Integer.MaxValue - 1
        End If
    Next

    Dim result As Integer = dCurrent(maxi)
    Return If((result > threshold), Integer.MaxValue, result)
End Function

Private Shared Sub Swap(Of T)(ByRef arg1 As T, ByRef arg2 As T)
    Dim temp As T = arg1
    arg1 = arg2
    arg2 = temp
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: That's the way I mentioned ;-) I believe that this will work.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the build-in soundex function of MySQL.

`SELECT SOUNDEX(name) FROM table;`

Or, the better way, there are a few MySQL-functions on the web implementing DoubleMetaphone. I think this is what you are searching:
[GitHub](https://github.com/AtomBoy/double-metaphone)

Comment: thank you, but as far as I understand soundex won't work if for example the name is inverted.. (Marco dell orso -> Dell orso marco) looking into the the double metaphone.

Comment: DM should work for you. I use it, too. I have to look for similarities not in english, too. I can tell you some more functions, not only for MySQL, even for VB. Maybe it would be better to use a function for similarity instead of a phonetic function.

Comment: might be.. I will try it.. meanwhile I updated the question, could give some more ideas.